# electron-rebuild with erlpack

Tags: c++, node.js, c, electron

When I tryin' to build erlpack using electron-rebuild I have that error:

```
⠴ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  adler32.c
⠹ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  compress.c
⠴ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  crc32.c
⠇ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  deflate.c
⠸ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  gzclose.c
⠦ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  gzlib.c
⠏ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  gzread.c
⠹ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  gzwrite.c
⠴ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  infback.c
⠏ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  inffast.c
⠹ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  inflate.c
⠧ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  inftrees.c
⠋ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  trees.c
⠼ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  uncompr.c
⠴ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  zutil.c
⠇ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  win_delay_load_hook.cc
⠦ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  zlib.vcxproj -> C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\Release\\zlib.lib
⠇ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  erlpack.cc
⠋ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0C:\Users\kaban\.electron-gyp\14.2.4\include\node\v8.h(1683,55): warning C4996: 'v8::Module::ResolveCallback': Use ResolveModuleCallback [C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack
.vcxproj]
C:\Users\kaban\.electron-gyp\14.2.4\include\node\v8.h(8720,7): warning C4996: 'v8::HostImportModuleDynamicallyCallback': Use HostImportModuleDynamicallyWithImportAssertionsCallback instead [C:\Users\kaban\Desk
top\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
⠏ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0  win_delay_load_hook.cc
⠧ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0     Creating library C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\Release\erlpack.lib and object C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\Release\erlpack.exp
⠏ Building module: erlpack, Completed: 0erlpack.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::shared_ptr<class v8::BackingStore> __cdecl v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore(void)" (__imp_?GetBackingStore@Arra
yBuffer@v8@@QEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@VBackingStore@v8@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl Unpack(class Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<class v8::Value> const &)" (?Unpack@@YAXAEBV?$FunctionCallbackInfo@VValue 
@v8@@@Nan@@@Z) [C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcxproj]
C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\Release\erlpack.node : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack\build\erlpack.vcx 
proj]
✖ Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1



Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\erlpack'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1


    at NodeGyp.rebuildModule (C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-type\node-gyp.js:117:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuildNodeGypModule (C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:94:9)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuild (C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:124:14)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuildModuleAt (C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:145:13)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuild (C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:108:17)
    at async C:\Users\kaban\Desktop\apps\cybercord\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\cli.js:154:9
```

When i trying to build this using node-gyp that creates build folder with some files but without .node file idk why

Versions:
Node: v16.13.2
Npm: 8.1.2
Electron Rebuild: 3.2.7

I don't know why that's not working
So I'm asking for help